# unset a property from a mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server side code tries to remove the property abc from a document in the users collection but it does not remove it when I check on the mongodb console.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```js
Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$unset: {abc: ""}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$unset: {abc: 1}});
```

I agree that the syntax is confusing: `1` actually stands for `true`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a `1`, any value will unset it.  This is straight from the [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/):

> The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.

Comment: not in the meteor framework, I'm afraid. Go figure why... I had the same issue than him, and my fix worked, as far as I can tell.